# "Sorry, this file has been deleted or moved." while opening file in Microsoft Teams after uploading it using C# code

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams

I have been facing the issue

> Sorry, this file has been deleted or moved

when I am trying to open a file(word, PPT, Excel, etc) in Microsoft Teams which I have uploaded using c# code successfully using Microsoft Graph API. I am able to download the uploaded file from Microsoft Teams but cannot see in Microsoft Teams itself. Also, I am able to upload the same file to the channel manually and it is getting opened in the Microsoft Teams successfully.

Code:

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

List<ChatMessageAttachment> chatMessageAttachments = new List<ChatMessageAttachment>();

Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();

chatMessage.Body.Content = chatMessage.Body.Content +
"<attachment id=" + "\"" + guid.ToString() + "\"" + "></attachment>";

ChatMessageAttachment chatMessageAttachment = new ChatMessageAttachment();

chatMessageAttachment.Id = guid.ToString();
chatMessageAttachment.Name = file.name;
chatMessageAttachment.ContentUrl = "https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/sites/testTeam/Shared%20Documents/General" + "/" + file.name; 
chatMessageAttachment.ContentType = "reference";

chatMessageAttachments.Add(chatMessageAttachment);

await graphClient.Teams[currentTeam.Id].Channels[currentChannel.Id].Messages
                                .Request()
                                .AddAsync(chatMessage);
```

Can anybody please suggest what went wrong in the code while uploading the file?

Comment: Can you please check the permission for the file in sharepoint?

Comment: Yes, I checked the permission of the file and the user has permission. I think the issue is with the URL being constructed when opening the file in Microsoft Teams. Please suggest.

Comment: Can you the URL within Teams for that file and see if you are able to access that file?

Comment: I have tried to open the file within Teams using file teams URL but it's giving the same error(Title). I tried to open SharePoint link of that file using "Get link" in Teams but it's giving the same below error in the SharePoint page.

Sorry, something went wrong
Item does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.

Comment: Can you once verify the content URL provided Bot and Teams sharepoint URL?

Comment: Yes, I have checked both but it's not opening yet in Microsoft Teams.

Comment: This may be possible that you don't have access to the file directory or item is deleted by someone

Answer (score 0):

Finally, The issue has been resolved. It was the problem of GUID which we are assigning to the chatMessageAttachment variable and this GUID should be of the uploaded file in SharePoint, not the newly created one.

This way I am able to view the uploaded file in Microsoft Teams itself.

**Updated Code**:

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

var chatMessage = new ChatMessage
{
  Body = new ItemBody
  {
    ContentType = BodyType.Html,
    Content = "Hello World"
  }
};

List<ChatMessageAttachment> chatMessageAttachments = new List<ChatMessageAttachment>();

using (var clientContext = new ClientContext(sharePointWebUrl))
{

clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, passWord);
clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web web = clientContext.Web;

Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File spfile = clientContext.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(web.ServerRelativeUrl + "Shared%20Documents/General" + "/" + file.name);    
clientContext.Load(spfile);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem item = spfile.ListItemAllFields;
clientContext.Load(item);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

string fileGuid = item["UniqueId"].ToString();

chatMessage.Body.Content = chatMessage.Body.Content +
"<attachment id=" + "\"" + fileGuid + "\"" + "></attachment>";

ChatMessageAttachment chatMessageAttachment = new ChatMessageAttachment();

chatMessageAttachment.Id = fileGuid; 
chatMessageAttachment.Name = file.name;
chatMessageAttachment.ContentUrl = "https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/sites/testTeam/Shared%20Documents/General" + "/" + file.name; 

chatMessageAttachment.ContentType = "reference";

chatMessageAttachments.Add(chatMessageAttachment);

chatMessage.Attachments = chatMessageAttachments;

await graphClient.Teams[currentTeam.Id].Channels[currentChannel.Id].Messages
                                .Request()
                                .AddAsync(chatMessage);
}
```

Please find below the document reference.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=csharp&viewFallbackFrom=graph-rest-1.0#example-4-file-attachments